# Implement COM IDispatch without ATL

Tags: c++, c, qt, com

I am writing an Excel RTD server implementation and I'm stuck on the boilerplate for a coclass which implements `IDispatch`. I have no access to ATL, but I am using ActiveQt, although I'm interested in how to do this in raw C or C++ too. How to properly implement the `IDispatch` methods in a COM server?

The documentation is just panickingly awful, as always. What I have so far read:

- It is better practice to [delegate the `IDispatch` method calls to some `ITypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Is this correct?
- If so, how to get an `ITypeInfo` to myself? [LoadTypeLib()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and family (followed by looking at `ITypeLib::GetTypeInfo()`)?
- If not, how is it implemented properly? Links to good-quality documentation and self-contained examples are of much use.

The `LoadTypeLib()` approach seems appropriate for a COM *client* to reach type information for some library, not for a COM server trying to introspect itself. Am I correct?

Comment: Typically, you implement IDispatch by paying Microsoft to give you a copy of ATL.  The documentation dates back to about 1999 when ATL wasn't available. Now, ATL is how you do it. Period. (I have implemented IDispatch. I wouldn't recommend the experience, it's hard work and a lot of typing.)

Comment: @Ben: Well, I agree with you that this is probably the cheapest way. Those damn troll technologies. (I lied: I do have access to ATL, but not in my workstation, and I just wanted to know if I could get along without it. But hey, tell no one about it, ok?)

Comment: I found "Inside COM+ Base Services" very helpful "back when" - it has a chapter on automation, which covers implementing `IDispatch`.

Comment: Hey, maybe Qt has a way to do it. What do I know about Qt? Not a lot.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Awesome, http://www.thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/, thank you. Skimming through the `IDispatch` part gives me an implementation using `ITypeInfo` and `LoadTypeLib()` as I've mentioned. @Ben: I'm afraid Qt doesn't have much code dealing with this.

Comment: @Alek, look at Noseratio answer below, it seems using ITypeInfo is not that hard after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the interface is properly defined in the IDL and compiled into a type library, implementing `IDispatch` via the type library's `ITypeInfo` is quite feasible as it's mostly delegating. The interesting part is `ITypeInfo::Invoke` which relies upon correct C++ v-table layout:

```
public class CComClass: public IDualInterface
{
    // ...

    // implementing IDualInterface

    ITypeInfo* m_pTypeInfo // can be obtained via ITypeLib::GetTypeInfoOfGuid for the GUID of IDualInterface

    // IDispatch
    STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfoCount(UINT* pctinfo)
    {
        *pctinfo = 1;
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfo(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** pptinfo)
    {
        if (0 != itinfo)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        (*pptinfo = m_pTypeInfo)->AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID* rgdispid)
    {
        return m_pTypeInfo->GetIDsOfNames(rgszNames, cNames, rgdispid);
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
    {
        return m_pTypeInfo->Invoke(static_cast<IDualInterface*>(this), dispidMember, wFlags, pdispparams, pvarResult, pexcepinfo, puArgErr); 
    }
}
```

I've used a similar approach to create [a script-callable wrapper for MSHTML DOM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18725302/1768303) to bypass scripting security restrictions.

So where do you get the ITypeInfo from? Essentially you get it by:

1. Write an IDL file which declares your interface as a **dual** interface. It has to be a dual interface, as that is how the `ITypeInfo` implementation knows which function to invoke - it cannot just invoke the C++ functions directly on your class because C++ has no reflection and because it is language neutral. Therefore it can only delegate the `Invoke` call to another method declared in the type library.
2. Compile the IDL to a header file and type library as part of the build process
3. The header file produced from the IDL defines the interface, which your implementing class must inherit from. Once you have implemented all the methods you are good to go. (For development start by making them all return `E_NOTIMPL` then implement them one by one)
4. Install the Type Library, either to the destination directory, or as a resource in the EXE/DLL. It will need to be registered by calling `RegisterTypeLib`. If it is embedded as a resource, you should call this from your `DllRegisterServer` implementation.
5. Load the type library when the first instance of your object is created, using `LoadTypeLib`. This gives you an `ITypeLib`
6. Get the ITypeInfo you need using `GetTypeInfoOfGuid`.

Comment: Are you sure in this case ITypeInfo::Invoke doesn't call the IDispatch::Invoke of the instance (which is a chicken and egg problem then)?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I'm pretty much sure. It uses the binary v-table layout of the dual interface and it's aware of the first 7 entries, starting from `AddRef`.

Comment: I understand the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221652(v=vs.85).aspx differently: "When called, ITypeInfo::Invoke performs the actions described by the IDispatch::Invoke parameters on the specified instance."

Comment: @SimonMourier, have a look at ATL's implementation of IDispatchImpl::Invoke in atlcom.h (more specifically, CComTypeInfoHolder::Invoke). It does pretty much the same. IMO, MSDN wording is correct, albeit vague.

Comment: Hmm... right. That was my first idea, and answered that initially but deleted my answer. I have undeleted it now :-)

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks for this very generous explanation. I haven't got enough time yet to work on this, but I'll let you know if everything went good soon.

Comment: @alek, It's still the better answer, even without that half!

Comment: After quite a long while (since I moved away from this issue, and now I've returned to it), I can say that this method works _perfectly_. Thank you very, very much Noseratio! Some observations: 1. I couldn't find anything related to `IDualInterface`, I merely used `IDispatch` instead; 2. The MSDN documentation regarding registration is faux and http://stackoverflow.com/a/285060/259543 gives the right way. In particular, you _will_ need `HKCR\Software\CLSID\<CLSID>\Programmable` for your component to appear in e.g. Microsoft Excel. I even intend to write a _proper_ article on how to do this.

Answer (score 10):

Implementing IDispatch can be easy or hard. (Assuming you cannot use ATL).

The easy way is to not support TypeInfo (return 0 from `GetTypeInfoCount` and `E_NOTIMPL` from `GetTypeInfo`. Nobody should call it.).

Then all you have to support is `GetIDsOfNames` and `Invoke`. It's just a big lookup table essentially.

For `GetIDsOfNames`, return `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME` if `cNames != 1`. You aren't going to support argument names. Then you just have to lookup `rgszNames[0]` in your mapping of names-to-ids.

Finally, implement Invoke. Ignore everything except   pDispParams and pVarResult. Use VariantChangeType to coerce the parameters to the types you expect, and pass to your implementation. Set the return value and return. Done.

The hard way is to use ITypeInfo and all that. I've never done it and wouldn't. ATL makes it easy so just use ATL.

If picking the hard way, Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ben. While you're still here, why using `ITypeInfo` be harder than implementing by hand? It seemed easier to me at first glance, although I thought it was inappropriate to implement it that way.

Comment: The difficulty with using ITypeInfo is primarily the time you have to spend working out how to use it. Sometimes it is just easier to do a small job the hard way because there is no learning curve. If I was doing *many* IDispatch implementations I might find it worthwhile to find out how to use it...

Comment: Another factor I personally lean on for not dealing with IDL and loading type libraries is that I haven't found a way to load a library from some embedded TLB file (embedded in my built program), as opposed to carrying the build TLB file around with the application, since it is loaded at runtime. So I just use the method proposed in this answer. If there was a way to "automatically" load the type library from an embedded TLB (compiled by the MIDL compiler or otherwise), I'd probably use it.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use a [Type Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you have one, that's one thing you won't have to do. If you don't have one, then you can create one using the [MIDL compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That's a free tool that comes with the Platform SDK. Of course in this case, it will mean you will have to write an IDL file (which can be a lot of work but you only need to define what you want). Depending on the kind of COM object you're targeting, an IDL file may already be available in the SDK. Once you have that IDL ready, you can compile it and [get back a TLB file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms220993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Once you have that TLB file, you can load it using the [LoadTypeLib function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Once you have an [ITypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference, you can load the [ITypeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221696%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you need (there may be more than once), and basically route IDispatch calls (GetIDsOfNames, etc.) into ITypeInfo implementation calls, as they are very similar.