# Non-MFC replacement for the AfxConnectionAdvise for Microsoft COM objects in mingw

Tags: c++, com, mfc, mingw

I am trying to implement a DDiskFormat2DataEvents class to listen to an IDiskFormat2Data's progress events. The only example I found of connecting those two uses  AfxConnectionAdvise. This project builds in mingw64 so I need to find an alternative to this MFC method or how to manually connect the com object's source and sink. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: VS includes the source code to MFC. Might want to take a look at the implementation to get a few ideas of where to start.

Comment: Thanks @Captain. I had looked but not to hard since I assumed the source was not there. I will take a closer look.

Comment: You're welcome. Forgot to point out that given the function name you'll likely want to start with [`IConnectionPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694318(v=vs.85).aspx.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty straightforward connection point implementation.  I found [this](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/242826-full) (link in german, but the code's pretty straightforward) - needs error checking, though.

Most of the work is setting up an IDispatch implementation with ITypeInfo. You could directly implement GetIDsOfNames and Invoke (without using ITypeInfo), but I find it's simpler to use ITypeInfo with event interfaces (since the typeinfo is already built).

You might also want to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253471/implement-com-idispatch-without-atl), too.

```
// pConnectTo = IDiscFormat2Data-Interface 
// riid = IID_DDiscFormat2DataEvents 
// pUnknown = The Event Receiver ( see below)
void connect(IUnknown* pConnectTo, REFIID riid, IUnknown* pUnknown) 
{ 
// QI the container
 HRESULT hr = pConnectTo->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&m_connContainer); 

// Find the connection point:
 hr = m_connContainer->FindConnectionPoint(riid, &m_connPoint); 

// Set up advice link
 DWORD cookie; 
 hr = m_connPoint->Advise(pUnknown, &cookie); 

// Retain the cookie:
 m_dwCookie = cookie; 
} 


// The Event Receiver (implicitly derives from IDispatch): 
class EventReceiver : public DDiscFormat2DataEvents 
{ 
public: 
    EventReceiver();
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Update(IDispatch* object, IDispatch* progress); 
private:
    com_ptr_t<ITypeInfo> m_ptinfo;
};

EventReceiver::EventReceiver()
{
    m_ptinfo = NULL; 

    HRESULT hr = 0; 
    LPTYPELIB ptlib = NULL; 

    hr = LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_IMAPILib2, IMAPILib2_MajorVersion, IMAPILib2_MinorVersion, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &ptlib)); 

    if (!FAILED(hr))
    { 
        hr = ptlib->GetTypeInfoOfGuid(IID_DDiscFormat2DataEvents, &m_ptinfo)); 
        ptlib->Release(); 
    }
}

// boilerplate IDispatch implementation based on Typeinfo
STDMETHODIMP EventReceiver::GetTypeInfoCount(UINT FAR *pctinfo) 
{ 
     *pctinfo = 1; 

     return NOERROR; 
} 

 STDMETHODIMP EventReceiver::GetTypeInfo(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo FAR * FAR *pptinfo) 
{ 
     *pptinfo = NULL; 

     if (itinfo != 0) return ResultFromScode(DISP_E_BADINDEX); 

     m_ptinfo->AddRef(); 

     *pptinfo = m_ptinfo; 

     return NOERROR; 
} 

 STDMETHODIMP EventReceiver::GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, OLECHAR FAR * FAR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID FAR *rgdispid) 
{ 
     return DispGetIDsOfNames(m_ptinfo, rgszNames, cNames, rgdispid); 
} 

 STDMETHODIMP EventReceiver::Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS FAR *pdispparams, VARIANT FAR *pvarResult, EXCEPINFO FAR *pexcepinfo, UINT FAR *puArgErr) 
{ 
     return DispInvoke(this, m_ptinfo, dispidMember, wFlags, pdispparams, pvarResult, pexcepinfo, puArgErr); 
}
```