# C++: DCOM events without ATL or MFC

Tags: c++, com

I need a good example of basic DCOM `dispinterface` implementation on both server and client size, but without ATL. It seems to me an impossible task to find some, because everything about COM is relying on ATL.
The best would be a working code of client and server, but a list of to-do steps would be of help, too. I think that actual implementation would be easier if it's clear what have to be done.

Comment: Some inputs here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253471/implement-com-idispatch-without-atl

Comment: That guy is looking how to implement IDispatch in server. I already have that, but thanks anyway. I'm looking how to implement `IConnectionPointContainer`, `IConnectionPoint` and so on...